# how to select .class:before , .class:after by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
.left_data{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
    background: #f00;
    border: 4px solid #f00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66)
    }

.left_data:after, .left_data:before {
    left: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.left_data:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-left-color: #f00;
    border-width: 30px;
    top: 20%;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.left_data:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-left-color: #f00;
    border-width: 36px;
    top: 20%;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

i need to select this classes by jquery to edit them 
.left_data:after ,  .left_data:before
I'm tryig to use this code but i get error

```
$(".left_data:after").css("border-left-color","#FFF");
```

Comment: I don't think its possible.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` styling does not actually exist in the DOM so jQuery can't do anything to it.

Comment: That's not how pseudo-classes work. Unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: the work around is to add another class to the node and overwrite styling in css based on the added class